# LEGO brick competitors?

Tags: 3rd-party

I'm trying to find all the competitors to LEGO. I know there is MegaBloks. What are some more?

The base idea is that they should be bricks and they need to connect to each other like LEGO. However, it does *not* need to be compatible with LEGO.

Also open source designs are always welcome!

Comment: Playmobil is the one I can never remember.

Comment: I don't think Playmobil really qualifies as "should be bricks and they need to connect to each other" - there are a few sets where you can build houses from a few different wall and floor pieces, but that was about it.

Answer (score 7):

- [Mega Bloks](http://www.megabloks.com/): the well-known Canadian brand
- [Oxford toys](http://www.oxfordtoy.co.kr/eng/index/index.asp) - [review](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/07/oxford-toys-overview/)
- Hasbro [KRE-O](http://www.hasbro.com/kre-o/)
- [K'Nex](http://www.knex.com/) - yes, they do [bricks](http://www.knex.com/building_toys/88_amp_energy_car.php) too (not sure about compatibility though)
- [Cobi](http://www.cobi.com.pl/en/)
- [Best-Lock](http://www.best-lock.com/)
- [Character Building](http://www.character-online.com/products/Character-Building/) from The Character Group, a range of licensed products including Dr Who, Deadly 60, HM Armed Forces and Ben 10 to name a few.

Disclaimer: some of these retrieved from the [lugnet](http://www.lugnet.com) [off-topic/clone-brands group](http://news.lugnet.com/off-topic/clone-brands/); they also mention ["Art Asylum’s C3 Brand"](http://www.artasylum.com/minisites/C3website/) but the site doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased my question a little off. I want to know if there's any LEGO like bricks that's _not_ compatible with LEGO.

Comment: Both questions have merit, so you may want to edit your original question to ask for both.

Comment: The connectivity of K'NEX bricks are amazing, they are designed for builds that undergo torque and pressure.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of semi/incompatible systems, there's a number of them that are supported through the [Free Universal Construction Kit](http://fffff.at/free-universal-construction-kit/) files for MakerBots and other 3D printers:

> The Free Universal Construction Kit offers adapters between Lego, Duplo, Fischertechnik, Gears! Gears! Gears!, K’Nex, Krinkles (Bristle Blocks), Lincoln Logs, Tinkertoys, Zome, and Zoob.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the resources mentioned by others, you might also be interested in this excellent compilation of all LEGO knockoff products and competitors titled Communist LEGO. It is in a form of a PDF and is a highly enjoyable read: http://www.1000steine.com/brickset/miscellaneous/clonebrands.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a [pretty complete listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_clone) as well.

> - Ausini
> - BanBao
> - Best-Lock
> - Brictek
> - Built to Rule
> - Cobi
> - Character Options
> - CoCo
> - Cogo
> - Enlighten Brick
> - K'nex (Note: some sets feature Lego-compatible studs)
> - Kre-O
> - Laser Pegs
> - Lite Brix
> - Mega Bloks
> - Nintendo (Manufactured Nintendo Block, later rebranded N&B Block)
> - Oxford
> - Rokenbok
> - Sluban
> - SY
> - Star Diamond
> - Tyco Super Blocks
> - Super Blox

From the back of my head, I would also add

- Ionix (Tenkai Knights)
- Nanoblock

Answer (score 0):

LEGO-like, but not compatible?
Nano Blocks.
http://www.mynanoblock.com/site/

Answer (score 0):

Montini; made in the '60's in The Netherlands, but Lego put a stop to that. Compatible underside in alternative positions if Lego doesn't have hollow stud for ×2's (the ×1's okay), as has pins, studs taller so Lego plate leaves a gap.

Large Mega Blocks fits atop Duplo, although they also make fully compatible.

Tente of Spain, hollow studs, brick with same N° of studs rests atop Lego, but not holding on.

Unknown British, a fraction smaller as using inches, used it at primary school in the 1960's.

Pennybrix, ~1964 by tri-ang. L-shaped studs.